# I can't use the pywinauto and White library, says FAIL: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Get'

Tags: python, robotframework, ui-automation, pywinauto

**I'm using Ride - Robot Framework - Automation WPF (app windows desktop)**
I can't use the pywinauto and White library, says FAIL: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Get'

```
*** Settings ***
Library           ../../../../Python37/Lib/site-packages/WhiteLibrary/
Library           ../../../../Python37/Lib/site-packages/pywinauto/

*** Variables ***
${APPLICATION}    C:/Users/Desktop/setup.exe

*** Test Cases ***
testfirstapp
    Launch Application    ${APPLICATION}
    sleep    3s
    Click Button    btnNext
=======================================================================================================================================
testfirstapp                                                                                                                   | FAIL |
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Get'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProjectTest                                                                                                             | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
20200615 22:06:42.475 :  INFO : Slept 3 seconds
20200615 22:06:42.492 :  FAIL : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Get'
```

Comment: Can you provide Python code snippet and full traceback? This output is not informative.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use full path for installed libraries. You should have them found from PYTHONPATH properly setup.

Replace:

```
Library           ../../../../Python37/Lib/site-packages/WhiteLibrary/
Library           ../../../../Python37/Lib/site-packages/pywinauto/
```

By:

```
Library           WhiteLibrary
Library           PywinautoLibrary
```

Note: Be sure that the libraries support your Python 3.7 version.